# Does Firefox, IE, Opera or Safari support OOPIF? (Out-of-Process iFrame, multi-threading)

Tags: javascript, html, multithreading, iframe, web-worker

Since Google Chrome v55 (and some previous versions) support for OOPIF (multi-threading iframes) is enabled by default. This provides many of the benefits of a WebWorker without startup latency and with full access to DOM.

https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/oop-iframes

https://github.com/optimalisatie/exec.js/tree/master/tests (OOPIF vs WebWorker)

Does Firefox, Internet Explorer, Opera and/or Safari offer (or are planning to offer) something similar?

I've read about GeckoView and webview. It appears that Firefox has been working on it for mobile.

Comment: A message by Chrome dev team: "In case you haven't seen it in our OOPIF status emails, we have enabled --isolate-extensions mode by default in M55.  This means that Chrome will use out-of-process iframes (OOPIFs) to put web iframes in a separate process from an extension parent frame, and vice versa.  This affects Windows, Mac, Linux, and ChromeOS, but not yet Android.  50% of M54 Beta users on these platforms also have this mode enabled."

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-dev/qlI54-dK4Ac